# PlantUML: How to generated large state machine (50 states) in GUI full?

Tags: plantuml

I have a plantuml state machine file. It has 50 state objects. When generating PNG diagram, the diagram just has partial view, it cut out as shown below:

[image: screenshot]

I then changed the image type to SVG, this time all the objects are generated, but the weird thing is the background are some sort of interleaved dark/light pattern:

[image: svg screenshot]

My questions:

1. How to resolve the PNG cut-off?
2. How to reset SVG background to clear?

Comment: Which version of plantuml are you using? Please share the state diagram code in the question

Answer (score 2):

You can influence the desired resolution with a statement like

```
skinparam dpi 300
```

The default resolution is 96 dots per inch.

Another option is to scale the image:

```
scale max 1024 width
scale 768 height
```

This is documented with additional variants in https://plantuml.com/de/commons.

As discussed [here](https://forum.plantuml.net/4894/background-color-of-an-svg-not-setting), SVG does use a transparent background, depending on the software which displays the SVG. The black-and-white checkerboard indicates the transparent regions.

Select the best orientation to fully utilize the output area:

```
left to right direction
```

Try if the following has a effect on your background:

```
skinparam backgroundColor #AAAAAA
```